# Creating A Faux Domain

Tags: .htaccess, ubuntu, nginx, dns

I'm using a web platform for my real estate business that "due to technical reasons" cannot offer subdomains.  Instead, if an individual in my company wants credit for the leads that come in due to their own marketing efforts, they would be required to manually add a url parameter to every link they share. (ie. ?agent=xxxxx)    This is clearly absurd.

I could write a chrome plugin or bookmarklets that add the agent= parameter for them, but this isn't a universal solution.

If it possible to host a "faux" domain which would function like it's own website, but pull all it's resources from my main website?  (While adding in the url parameter that triggers the tracking cookie)

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: What does "cannot offer subdomains" actually mean? Often http servers are configured to use a "default host", so that all host names with a DNS resolution pointing to that host name are responded to. So even without explicit support you would receive the requests and your application logic could extract the requested host name from the request data.

Comment: Apart from that it certainly is possible to operate additional http hosts that just operate as proxies, relaying requests and responses between client and main http server. But if that is an option, then why don't you simply move your whole application to another service provider which does not have such an annoying limitation.

Comment: @arkascha I'm not exactly sure of their technical limitations, but you're 100% correct they *should* be able to achieve some sort of subdomain functionality regardless of what their setup is.  However they either can't or are unwilling to.  There's many platforms that offer exactly what they do, hower the next best option with subdomain support will cost me ~ $100 a month more and I'd have to manually migrate, or pay someone to do it.   If I could achieve what I want on a $5 a month VPS that would be a better option. :)

Comment: Not sure if you understood what I wrote. DNS resolution for example can be controlled independent of your hosting provider. And you certainly can operate a VPS, sure, but you should also consider the disadvantages: low performance compared to a hosting platform with fast servers and CDN support, you are completely on your own in maintenance and mid layer setup, you indeed have to manually move. Oh and... btw... hosting service providers that support what you call "sub domains" (actually it is host names) do _not_ generally charge 100$ a month...